# Show UISearchController's SearchResultsController on SearchBar Tap

Tags: ios, uisearchcontroller

I am using UISearchController not UISearchDisplayController, and I want to show SearchResultController on SearchBar Tap right away. Right now it's showing like this (when I tap on the search bar):

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When results are empty, `UISearchController`'s `viewController` is still hidden. That's why we have to fiddle our way around using `UISearchControllerDelegate`'s `willPresentSearchController:`

#### After initializing `self.searchController` make your ViewController conform to `UISearchControllerDelegate:

```
self.searchController.delegate = self;
```

#### Implement `willPresentSearchController:` in your ViewController:

```
- (void)willPresentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        searchController.searchResultsController.view.hidden = NO;
    });
}
```

The async dispatch is necessary, because otherwise it will be overridden by the internal behavior. You could go fancy here and use an animation to have the table view fade in.

#### Additionally, implement `didPresentSearchController:` for sanity:

```
- (void)didPresentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
{
    searchController.searchResultsController.view.hidden = NO;
}
```

Comment: it works only for the first time when tap anything from the Search Results Controller when you again tap Search Bar it doesn't show the Search Results Controller.

Comment: Did you try implementing the counter delegate methods `didDismissSearchController:` and `willDismissSearchController:`? Set inside of those methods `searchController.searchResultsController.view.hidden = YES;`.

Comment: I did but it didn't have any effect on it.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it with the sample code (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html). Are the delegate methods being called when you tap the second time?

Comment: willPresentSearchController and didPresentSearchController does't get called second time and willDismissSearchController & didDismissSearchController only gets called when I tap Cancel button of the Search Bar. I have developed a repos on [github](https://github.com/attiqeurrehman/UISearchController) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Use self.searchController.active = NO;` instead of `[self.searchController.searchBar resignFirstResponder];` when calling `didShowFavourite`.
There's also no need to implement the delegate methods for dismissal.

Comment: it worked, please update the answer as well so others can benefit from it as well.

Comment: @tubtub This works great for the first launch. If we type something and then remove the entered text completely, the resultsController gets hidden again. Is there a way to solve this too?

Answer (score 9):

I found that the other answers had flickering due to using `dispatch_async`. They used this so that their changes would be applied after the internal behavior of the search controller had completed, but this leaves a couple frames where the internal behavior is applied before it is overridden. Using KVO allowed me to immediately override the internal behavior without any flickering.

I also found that the other answers did not keep the search results controller visible when a user tapped the ⓧ button to clear the contents of the search bar, which seems incorrect to me.

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    ...
    self.searchController.delegate = self;
    [self.searchController.searchResultsController.view addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"hidden" options:0 context:NULL];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context
{    
    if ( object == self.searchController.searchResultsController.view &&
         [keyPath isEqualToString:@"hidden"] &&
         self.searchController.searchResultsController.view.hidden &&
         self.searchController.searchBar.isFirstResponder )
    {
        self.searchController.searchResultsController.view.hidden = NO;
    }
}

- (void) willPresentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
{
    searchController.searchResultsController.view.hidden = NO;
}

- (void) searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if ( searchText.length == 0 )
        self.searchController.searchResultsController.view.hidden = NO;
}


- (void) searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    self.searchController.searchResultsController.view.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: So far, this has been the most effective answer. The observer is the key (pun mildly intended)

Comment: Thank you for a great solution! But may I ask you why do you handle searchBar: textDidChange method if you already have  an observer set up for this purpose?

Comment: It's been a while since I've looked at this, but it looks like the observer only handles the changing "hidden" property, whereas searchBar:textDidChange: detects when the last bit of text is removed, and hides the search results controller. It looks like they're accomplishing two different things.

Answer (score 5):

Chris Vasselli's answer is the cleanest way to implement this.

**Here it is in Swift 3**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    searchController.delegate = self
    self.searchController.searchResultsController?.view.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "hidden", options: [], context: nil)
}


override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

    if let someView: UIView = object as! UIView? {

        if (someView == self.searchController.searchResultsController?.view &&
            (keyPath == "hidden") &&
            (searchController.searchResultsController?.view.isHidden)! &&
            searchController.searchBar.isFirstResponder) {

            searchController.searchResultsController?.view.isHidden = false
        }

    }
}


func willPresentSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) {
    searchController.searchResultsController?.view.isHidden = false
}


func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    if (searchText.characters.count == 0) {
        searchController.searchResultsController?.view.isHidden = false
    }
}


func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchController.searchResultsController?.view.isHidden = true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> I think this method is better, be careful when searchBar is empty then preload tableview will disappear again.

#### UISearchBarDelegate

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchText.isEmpty {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.searchController.searchResultsController?.view.hidden = false
        }
    }
}

func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.searchController.searchResultsController?.view.hidden = false
    }
}
```

#### UISearchControllerDelegate

```
func willPresentSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.searchController.searchResultsController?.view.hidden = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swfit 5 version** with simplified code

### ModuleBuilder

```swift
let resultViewController = YourResultViewController()
let searchBarController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultViewController)
searchBarController.searchBar.delegate = resultViewController as? UISearchBarDelegate
navigationItem.searchController = searchBarController
```

### YourResultViewController: UISearchBarDelegate

```swift
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchText.isEmpty {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.view.isHidden = false
        }
    }
}

func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.view.isHidden = false
    }
}
```