# UISearchController's UISearchDisplayController not showing

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller, uisearchbardelegate

Couple of months ago I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29196752/show-uisearchcontrollers-searchresultscontroller-on-searchbar-tap) to show the UISearchDisplayController and it worked like a charm but

Now I am presenting another controller after user taps on the *searchResultsController's* tableview cell and it selects a cell and hides the *searchResultsController* to show MapView but once you tap the search bar *searchResultsController* doesn't shows up but once you press cancel button and tap search bar again it starts working again.

Scenario is exactly the Apple's Maps app opening up favourite view along with recent view controller with segments.

Here's my code for UISearchControllerDelegate:

```
- (void)willPresentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
{
    mainViewController *__weak weakSelf=self;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        mainViewController *__strong strongSelf = weakSelf;
        strongSelf.searchController.searchResultsController.view.hidden = NO;
    });
}

- (void)didPresentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
{
    self.searchController.searchResultsController.view.hidden = NO;
}
```

And here is my code for UISearchBarDelegate.

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{

    mainViewController *__weak weakSelf=self;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        mainViewController *__strong strongSelf = weakSelf;
        strongSelf.searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
    });

    self.searchController.searchResultsController.view.hidden = NO;
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)searchBarShouldEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    mainViewController *__weak weakSelf=self;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        mainViewController *__strong strongSelf = weakSelf;
        strongSelf.searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
    });

    return YES;
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    mainViewController *__weak weakSelf=self;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        mainViewController *__strong strongSelf = weakSelf;
        strongSelf.searchController.searchResultsController.view.hidden = YES;
    });

    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    }];
}
```

Comment: `UISearchController` and `UISearchDisplayController` are different.

Comment: @PraveenGowdaIV I wanted to write SearchResultsController instead of UISearchDisplayController. Thanks for pointing it out.