# UISearchController: searchResultsController not displaying

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I am pretty new to UISearchController so pardon if this is a silly question.

I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29196752/show-uisearchcontrollers-searchresultscontroller-on-searchbar-tap) question but was not able to get the results I wanted.

In my `MapViewController's` `viewDidLoad` I initialize the search controller like so:

`searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: customViewController)`

where customViewController is a subclass UIViewController with some text labels for now (through interface builder). 
(I declare it like so: `let customViewController = MyCustomeViewController()`

I tried to follow the above link by hiding and unhiding the `searchResultsController` with `searchController.searchResultsController?.view.isHidden = false` in the delegate methods to no luck.

The result is the same: where only the view is dimmed.

Ideally I want it to be something similar to Facebook's app where when you tap the search bar it shows a different view.

I printed the `searchResultsController` object in the delegate `willPresentSearchController` and it does indicate it as `MyCustomViewController`.

Am I missing something here or is this not the right approach?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out that the controller to display needs to be a `UITableViewController`or a subclass of one. I tried a regular `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` inside it but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that @Simon's answer is not correct. I am able to use a `UIViewController` for the `searchResultsController`.

My issue was that the searchController itself was deallocated from memory because I did not retain it, in this case, as a class-wide instance.

In other words,

Instead of

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: MySearchResultsController())
...
self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchController.searchBar
// And add other delegates and stuff
```

I made a class-wide global and did

```
private var searchController : UISearchController!

...

self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: MySearchResultsController())
...

self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchController.searchBar
// And add other delegates and stuff
```